# Getting errors installing glmnet package using R studio

Tags: r, glmnet

I have been trying to install **glmnet** package from **RStudio**. I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on my system. This is the command I have used

```
install.packages("glmnet", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

I have not been able to install the package. Following is the error message.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/vamshi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/glmnet_2.0-16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3882584 bytes (3.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘glmnet’ ...
** package ‘glmnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-oNcpyf/r-base-3.5.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c glmnet5dp.f -o glmnet5dp.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-oNcpyf/r-base-3.5.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c glmnet_init.c -o glmnet_init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o glmnet.so glmnet5dp.o glmnet_init.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'glmnet.so' failed
make: *** [glmnet.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’
* removing ‘/home/vamshi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/glmnet’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpwiFSth/downloaded_packages’
```

Please help me out. I have also tried `install.packages("glmnet",dependencies="TRUE")` but still getting errors installing.

@saisaran

The output of sessionInfo() is as follows:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ISLR_1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1
```

Comment: From the description of [tag:rstudio]: `**Do not** use this tag for general R programming problems, just use the R tag. ONLY use for RStudio-specific questions.` It's a common mistake to closely associate RStudio with R, but they are distinct topics (one is an IDE, other is a language).

Comment: can u post u r `rsessioninfo()`

Comment: @saisaran. Pls check the output of sessionInfo() command in the question posted

Comment: This is unlikely to be an R problem. Try `apt-get install libgfortran3` on the console (as an admin user) to install the library that is required by the R package. In this question, I think the most indicative message is `cannot find -lgfortran`, which indicates it cannot find `libgfortran.so` anywhere in the library path. A [google search for ubuntu and libgfortran](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgfortran3) points to the package.

Comment: @r2evans. Thanks. It worked after I installed gfortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-oNcpyf/r-base-3.5.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c glmnet5dp.f -o glmnet5dp.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-oNcpyf/r-base-3.5.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c glmnet_init.c -o glmnet_init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o glmnet.so glmnet5dp.o glmnet_init.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgfortran

make: gfortran: cannot find -lgfortran

You either don't have a fortran compiler or its not accessible by your R instance. How you fix that depends on your operating system,

Solution:-

Type these two lines in your terminal, direct quote:

curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxj gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /

It will download you the gfortran for Mavericks (which is missing in your system at the moment) and will install it in your system. At least, this will solved your problem.

Comment: Is the macos version you suggested here completely compatible with the ubuntu system that the OP demonstrated? I would have expected the output from `sessionInfo()` to include `macOS` to be able to use the darwin version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's probably because you don't have libgfortran6 installed. If you use Arch Linux or Manjaro, just install **libgfortran6** with:

```
pacman -Syu libgfortran6
```

But for some reason, the default source in the aur doesn't work, you need to use git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git#commit=878763634f0a75699559b3c0b90d466954a6510f as source.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was installing the below

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran5
sudo apt-get install libgfortran-8-dev
```